# Set image size on desktop, but resize when using mobile

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to have an image set to a specific size while using a desktop browser, but have it automatically resize to your screen using a mobile device?

I currently just have the image hardcoded to a specific size in HTML.

```
<img src="URL" alt="Cool Link" style="width:720px;height:100px;border:0;">
```

I'm open to trying HTML/CSS/JS etc. Thanks!

Comment: Research [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). But in this case perhaps simply `width: 100%; max-width: 720px` on the image would suffice.

Comment: You can use CSS Media Queries for this. Refer to [this] (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: @Turnip was right, that solution works for both the width and height requirements I need to set. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You sholud add class attribute to img tag and then add below css for image

```
<img src="link" alt="Cool Link" class="anyofimgclass">

.anyofimgclass{
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Maybe max-width: 720px?

Comment: Why `display: block` ?

Answer (score 0):

As Arti Rana said, you should create a class first. 
Then you can use @media attribute, to set style for specific max-width. You can check this out here:

[CSS @media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

P.S. I recommend you to use containers ([div](https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_containers.asp)) in order to create classes.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
img {
  display:inline-block;
  width:768px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    img {
        width:100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://www.myhappyenglish.com/x9walos9f/uploads/2013/05/placeholder.png">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/6t2snwa3/6/

This works fine..Try this